# Chmodding only files which need it

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I'm trying to enforce that all directories have `g+rx` permissions, but the question is general: how to chmod only files which require it, by using `find`, instead of processing all files.

I tried this:

```
find /path -type d \! -perm /g+rx -exec chmod g+rx "{}" ";"
```

I read this as "find all directories under `/path` which do not have `g+rx` permissions and execute `chmod g+rx` on them".

But, looking at IO stats, this command always generates a lot of writes (edit: verified with `exec echo...`) so it chmods everything instead of just the directories which need it. On repeated executions, this shouldn't generate any writes.

Comment: Have you tried using `-exec echo chmod ...` on subsequent runs to see if `find` really is running `chmod` again?

Comment: Are you trying to be "efficient"?  I suspect that ``chmod -R g+rX`` might be faster than invoking multiple instances of chmod.

Comment: also, end the `-exec` with `+` rather than `;`, so it runs `chmod` as few times as possible with as many directory names as will fit into each command line, rather than running chmod once per matching directory.

Comment: Funnily `chmod` will "change" permissions of all files despite them potentially already having the correct permission. [Linux]

Comment: It's possible that you have "atime" enabled on your filesystem in which case read access also causes writes to disk to update the "atime" aka "access time" field of the involved directories. Configure to use `relatime` or `noatime` instead to save IO.

Comment: Use `mount | grep "^$(df . | sed 's! .*!!' | tail -n 1)"` to find out the mount options for the current directory. Look for the ones I proposed, as `atime` is probably the default.

Comment: @JonasBerlin relatime is the default since Linux 2.6.30, and it's present on this particular filesystem.

Comment: @StephenKitt yup, adding "echo" confirms it - the command in my post runs chmod over all directories.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. False alarm, sort of. My shell had an issue with using "!" to negate the test in `find`. When I replaced it with "-not", it started working as it should.